# AWS-CLI - Can't find my config even through it exists

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I installed Amazon Command Line Tools (AWS-CLI) using:

```
pip install awscli
```

It installed successfully. I then created a file in this location: **/opt/aws/aws_cred.txt**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XYZ
aws_secret_access_key = XYZ
region = XYZ
```

Then I ran this command:

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=”/opt/aws/aws_cred.txt”
```

Then I get this when I try to run this command: **aws ec2 describe-regions**

> botocore.exceptions.ConfigNotFound: 
>   The specified config file (”/opt/aws/aws_cred.txt”)
>   could not be found.

What else could I do? Does it need to be executable, owned by a certain user, what? The file is definitely there but it can't find it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134879/aws-the-config-profile-myname-could-not-be-found

Comment: You don't need quotes at all actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=”/opt/aws/aws_cred.txt”
```

and

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/opt/aws/aws_cred.txt"
```

(Hint: one uses "smart" quotes.)

Edit: to be less oblique, your use of smart quotes is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for it?

```
find / -name aws_cred
```